# iOS Search Calendar using title property

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calendar

I am trying to make an app that permits the user to make events in one specified calendar.

The problem is that:

I can't find a solution to know if there's a calendar with the title that I want to use.

If the list is empty I write a code that creates the calendar but if the list isn't empty I need to know if there's a calendar with the `calendar.title` that I need.

If there isn't any calendar, I create the calendar; if there is I add the event to this calendar.

Below is the code I am using:

```
EKEvent *myEvent;
EKEventStore *store;
EKSource* localSource;
EKCalendar* newCal;

store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore: store];
NSString* title         = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
NSString* location      = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];
NSString* message       = [arguments objectAtIndex:3];
NSString* startDate     = [arguments objectAtIndex:4];
NSString* endDate       = [arguments objectAtIndex:5];
NSString* calendarTitle = [arguments objectAtIndex:6];
//NSString* calID = nil;
//int i = 0;

EKCalendar* calendar = nil;
if(calendarTitle == nil){
    calendar = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;
} else {
    NSIndexSet* indexes = [store.calendars indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        *stop = false;
        EKCalendar* cal = (EKCalendar*)obj;
        if(cal.title == calendarTitle){
            *stop = true;
        }
        return *stop;
    }];

    if (indexes.count == 0) {
        //if list is empty i haven't calendars then i need to create it
        for (EKSource* source in store.sources)
        {
            if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
            {
                localSource = source;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!localSource) return;

        newCal = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:store];
        calendar.source = localSource;
        calendar.title = calendarTitle;

        NSError* error;
        bool success = [store saveCalendar:newCal commit:YES error:&error];

        if (error != nil)

        {
            NSLog(error.description);
        }
        //calendar created

    } else {

        //!Empty List i need to search the calendar with the title = calendarTitle
        //And if there isn't i need to create it



        //calendar = [store.calendars objectAtIndex:[indexes firstIndex]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your implementation of indexesOfObjectsPassingTest. You're not returning any indexes, and since you try to stop it after it finds one index, you should just use the singular version indexOfObjectPassingTest. You can very simply write that like this:

```
     NSUInteger* indx = [store.calendars indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(EkCalendar *cal, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     return [cal.title isEqualToString:calendarTitle];
    }];
```

Then, after checking to see that index is not NSNotFound use

```
calendar = store.calendars[indx];
```

Comment: I don't know i changed the code and now i can access to all calendars but when i call saveCalendar the calendar do not appear in calendar app.

I'm going crazy.

Comment: @MattiaSoravia, does this answer your question about finding the calendar with a particular title? If so, you should asccept my answer, and post a new question about your other problem